# How to type function return type with optional object of formatter function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to figure out how to properly type the return value when an object with optional formatter functions is involved.

For a function with a single value it is working fine.

```js
type Params = {
    id?: number
    created?: string
}

type FormatFn<TParam extends keyof Params, TValue> = (data: Params[TParam]) => TValue

type Result<TValue> = {
    param: TValue
}

declare function query<TParam extends keyof Params, TValue = Params[TParam]>(
    param: TParam,
    formatter?: FormatFn<TParam, TValue>
): Result<TValue>;

// Works as expected 'created' is type 'Date'
const { param: created } = query('created', (created) => new Date(created || ''))
```

I want to add a version where you can input an array of strings and an object of optional formatter functions.

Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQFwJwSwKYBNoHtoE8AODQENQBnOAWywBsEZQA3K41AO1ADM4ZCp9GU4uB3VDADWhfKAQAPHAGMoyAHQAoEKABCAVy4sh0ABa4SG8lDigAjhqoZa9OEwigkTAORc9eOtxszyV0Hqo-GhEUHgwUMpKUNi4AArheCRiALygAN5KoNmgcEgA-ABcoIwaJABGVFk5MjAIePIFxZzwjADmSgC%20StGxoABiQiQN-YwAPAAqCTBJEpLyPGLCCBioLKDTSYQANKATAGp4fggAfKBpABRIDXjFm8kA2lOJJAC6AJTnZwdHVj0xOFAACUEIRjFBJodjmc0pkcqAsC9ij9jl0ekgEL5wrgWBpGHJ7MxLNZJvc5gskEsVmsNi8dnsof40vdCE97q8ThdqtlETMSMj7ttuawhg15DAigNRVBRqSXrsUVYTkp3sUQWCTJDfqcANw9VQAdSEonwYikskaShkTE4GQRSNAtXqjVAnXOFisMAwFxcToayBcuwufsanxSZ0YCGCABF-cG6v6UAAfJOgFwud7vfVgA0eLiQI6EdD8PCMLhQdAeOiFXqA%204AaRWqVAAEEYDMMGNlqt1izlbXcIMYMMoOK5XyzfMEItaXzGxh6YrQTCMsKHvXcsxnhOHqUKlRXq9ikOR7L6wrGaD1xy0QPgaDwYQtcdCCu4TleVtkZfCLeMVi6lYPECQcYl4FBcctnJadKVnJJ50XH9OWFT9kgFOkhXhHRhzFKhJRPXCYEg5IL21V8VTVB8TCfJdyKtG0uCMEw4AoXA0jAxBCAuB4XDyQM0xDANXl2d9skEpBinjZ1kDDCMo1AWN5CkxNQBTNMMy6LMVDAcBGE4eoUBpOooA0GBmABBBtNXVR4VQwhikyGz4RyPJij3SoYCFJznMdBNGmaWA4HaKz4W6VQwrAKzIBLMsQirXAoD0OB6UqGQ8A0QhcBpRKcWlcUgPxUwmCsxywFsukHJCnzcgkkoyg8ryyuq8TikUyzvNdKzOiAA) with my attempt.

This would be my expected output:

```js
queries(['id', 'created'], {
    created: (created) => new Date(created || '')
})

// Instead of return type
// {
//     params: {
//         id: number,
//         created: string
//     }
// }
// 
// I want to have this, because of the formatter function
// {
//     params: {
//         id: number,
//         created: Date
//     }
// }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type Params = {
    id?: number
    created?: string
}

type Elem = keyof Params;

type Fn = (value: any) => any

type Predicate<T extends Elem> = Record<T, (value: Required<Params>[T]) => any>

type Reducer<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? Reducer<Tail, Result & Predicate<H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never;

/**
 * Pure js/ts analogy
 */

const reducerPredicate = (elem: string) => ({ [elem]: () => null });

const reducer = <Arr extends string[]>(
    arr: Arr,
    result: { [prop: string]: string } = {}
) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return result; // 1. end of recursion, this is the last call
    }

    const [head, ...tail] = arr; // 2. from first and before the last

    return reducer(tail, { ...result, ...reducerPredicate(head) });
    // no need for never branch
};

type Result<
    P extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Params>,
    Defaults extends Partial<Record<keyof Params, Fn>>,
    Cache extends P[number] & keyof Defaults = P[number] & keyof Defaults> =
    & { [Prop in Exclude<P[number], Cache>]: Required<Params>[Prop] }
    & { [Prop in keyof Defaults]: Defaults[Prop] extends Fn ? ReturnType<Defaults[Prop]> : never }

function queries<TParams extends Array<keyof Params>, TValues extends Partial<Reducer<TParams>>>(
    params: [...TParams],
    formatter?: TValues
): Result<TParams, TValues> {
    return null as any
}

const multiple = queries(['id', 'created'], {
    created: (created /** string */) => 42,
    id: (value /** number */) => 42
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgoFQCWAJgPwBcUAdgK7IBGEC+hAxghHMBOVasARFqAc1wBfXLlCQoAUQA2EZJigBrCCAD2AM1iIUqANxSZ0AGLVVACgBucBbQhU41EAEpMAPiiuQp8GgYThIiNm4IAB4AFSgIAA8eahJ0RWUfLAAlCDYtBBIYgBooOwcnKmyAR1oiEMj4JDQvAG1ogF1PDB8-LwDZbJJaNmZI1gIAQQQEOMSIZPRsuBItagUQSaQQSLTkL0KxqGzUWgVgGaSUw5y8goEhUWKe1WxJQigMqA3zucvmtoOyFdjqcDlQvgkLuhOEsVmsoM1hDpmFAABLFAB0mMRyOicCICn+b0BuPx33mVxhq3WUzgWx2vSJqLJlx2AKug2GCBieIUxSOJzOADJYCEwhFIiivAzCFRqBBbMxQTR5Yq3rKVQgTLgAPQAKl1+F1sFonCgACtUNrgOhXA4tCJ-FBddqpLlqAIoCEhsxgrwxTwbBAlMh+IJhCJOj5rNh4UHlG0qNZIzQTgooOJ3Fq3R6vZzVJFwbNyXdw38vNYDogEGCpvs3pxgcAqDHmmAEFowKH7iIE1AS6J089JMm8G8iHprFX0UpRMAABaYDBYAAMnlHb0InGAJqsDYFRig2u1UAAjOi4skoLpPTkTagiCtivOiOgX1B59AFHAPeEFAoDpIBzZmczRzlwJAYpiwA8m0qhVgeR5QAATOeOjtioOi1B6rgkFATA6Hk0AflAX4CFI9YQNuCC7rw3oINY0H4sUMaYuie6nJBbG0ZyvqhOEPDWGBSyeBmJhvIh1BaMqvBQAR0xygq0wMEg1BsHOEhamYQICqMbwwMyCzgbC1KbJEGjaHoDSGHsBwACIQDocACugEI-OgDTAEQDiRNkuT5GZmjXlZaDFJYUp1oQADCcBqdArnkjAzR0IwzCwcK5nXvZjnOaoiXJUwCBpeogV6FlTmnKgGQHMKLbBB2xBWHI8RsI4JBRHl9AFW0xTRbFXi9lUNR1MFlXNHVYCwa8hA1fC40NcVFlQGVzm9stFVje2E0GVAlhQIC2RUdQ0SBJEa3WhtHZtD46qKemUg6LQqmeSsUDVMwRAQKgMQjdtGy0gFi0jXsUDRAAamUn3bR5XkKD53EjNEQNShWbxgAYaBUM0rGI+jqDdQccnINwPAIJQIPg44n24O4FSfTpOONKgxRgxDlU4AcW47imf6+DabgSK6KwesgApEGASiqG9QifdYzQAOSkHLxRyxwXA8CQcvdezbyqxEJCJrr6uHvqfZhgOzrJgALEhEUEKQib2JTxtGvlyIW94UDWxI7i4EAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce), in my blog, you can find more explanation.

Comment: this is awesome and almost works. It would be nice if `Fn` would be typed. The function should only get one value of the original param (id: number, created: string). Something like this `type Fn<V> = (value: V) => any`? I'm definitely missing some TS basics..

Comment: @fnn made an update several minutes ago. pls check

Comment: @fnn I have added pure js analogy of `reducer`. Also, here you can find some examples

Comment: Awesome. I was not aware that this is possible with TS. Your blog also helped!